# Safari is super slow at everything even after clear cache

Tags: macos, safari

On macOS with Safari I am having the issue that Safari operations for boot, creating new tabs and new windows are super slow.
Starting Safari takes between 45 seconds and 1 minute and 20 seconds even with no site from the previous session.
Creating a new tab or window takes between 30 seconds and a minute.
All have been timed.
I have been unable to identify why this happens, I have tried the following to solve the issue:

- Disable all extension (I only had Grammarly)
- Cleared cache
- Cleared history and cleared cache

Additionally I have tried the following:

- Create a new user
- Start in safe

The issue persists under these conditions as well.
The issue started roughly 3 months ago, but I do not recall and update.

Comment: Does the same happen in a freshly created user account?

Comment: @IconDaemon not iPad or iPhone this is on macos

Comment: @Ihf yes it happens on new accounts as well

Comment: Does this happen on other browsers like Google Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: Does it happen in [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac)?

Comment: @IconDaemon no it is only Safari

Comment: @Ihf yes it does happen in safe mode as well